# Passing further arguments with tagged template literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I'm working with [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) and generating components using their tagged template literal syntax such as:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: papayawhip;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: palevioletred;
`
```

In one case I need to call a function that generates a media query based on a breakpoint **and** passes the tagged template literal of css to be included within.

for example:

```
media(12)`
   background-color: papayawhip;
`
```

The media function might look something like this:

```
const media = mapValues(width => ({ css: (...args) => css`
  @media (min-width: ${width}rem) {
    ${css(...args)}
  }
`}));
```

Is passing both a value and a tagged template literal possible, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Why not media``min-width:${somevar}; background-color:papayawhip``

Comment: @Jonasw thanks for replying! The actual implementation is a bit more complex with media being called by mapping over an array of breakpoints. The media function needs to be separated from the main block of css in order for separation of concerns and for testing. The actual implementation can be viewed here: https://github.com/aaronvanston/react-flexa/blob/master/src/components/Col/Col.js#L16 this is slightly incorrect as I need more arguemtns passed into the media function.

Comment: i actually dojt know if it works, but wouldnt be media(12,`sth`); a solution?

Comment: @Jonasw I tried something similar to this, and the due to the way the tagged template literal is constructed it seems to only include the strings within it and not the variables. for instance media(12)`background-color: ${SOMEVAR}` would generate: `@media(min-width:12rem) { background-color:}` and skip the var.

Comment: it passes all the values as second argument to the tag. If passed to a function, the string should be constructed.

Comment: @Jonasw How would I update the mediaQuery method to accommodate this? 

for example: https://gist.github.com/aaronvanston/bc0b15fd68b24bcc05e6196261670b78

Comment: should work fine, however the css tag cant access the arguments anymore...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147939/discussion-between-aaron-vanston-and-jonas-w).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tagged template literals](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#tagged-template-literals) are no magic, you just need to return another function from your `media(12)` call:

```
function media(twelve) {
  return function(stringParts, ...interpolationValues) {
    return …
  }
}
```

or using arrow functions

```
const media = (twelve) => (stringParts, ...interpolationValues) => …;
```

to be called as

```
media(12)`firstPart ${13} secondPart`
// or equvialently
media(12)(["firstPart ", " secondPart"], 13)
```

However, if you don't need to do any interpolation but just want to receive a string, it might be easier to write a function with the parameters

```
function media(twelve, string) {
  return …;
}
```

and call it as

```
media(12, `
  templateString
`)
```

Comment: Thanks for laying this out! I got it working in the end with a similar approach, the strings being passed in were including commas, a temporal solution was to remove them, but may need to refactor the way it's being included. 

This is the exact line I'm refering to: https://github.com/aaronvanston/react-flexa/pull/62/files#diff-99a45c5816f379ef543d689b1a46dbbdR4